# Optimize Elastic Search query

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have recently added elasticsearch as search engine for a project, it's an ecommerce structure model, and i use it to load categories, manufacturers etc.

The queries typically run very fast around 200ms which is pretty good considering the number products i have as on some projects i have more than 1 milion products.

However in some cases, like on a simple category page where i have around 550k products in that category page, the query takes around 500ms, i am wondering if i can optimize it to be faster.

Please not that i have aggregations and more filters added in the  query depending on the options the customer selects, but for optimizing purposes i have removed them as i have the same loading speed with or without them.

This is the query which in that particular case takes around 500-600 ms

```
    Array
   (
    [size] => 48
    [from] => 0
    [sort] => Array
        (
            [date_upd] => Array
                (
                    [order] => desc
                )

        )

    [query] => Array
        (
            [bool] => Array
                (
                    [filter] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [term] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id_product_categories] => 38231
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

The elasticsearch index structure is as follows:
        $data = array(

```
                'settings' =>

                            array(
                                'number_of_shards' => 1,
                                'number_of_replicas' => 0,
                                'analysis' => $analysis,
                                'index' => array(
                                        'sort.field' => array('date_add','date_upd', 'reduction_percent','price'),
                                        'sort.order' => array('desc','desc','desc','desc')
                                )
                            ),

                'mappings' =>  array( 
                'product' => array(         
                                            //'type' => 'product',
                                            '_all' => array( 'enabled' => false),
                                            'properties' => array
                                                                (
                                                                    'id_product' => array(
                                                                        'type' => 'integer'),

                                                                    'id_image' =>array(
                                                                        'type' => 'integer', 
                                                                        'null_value' => 0 
                                                                    ),

                                                                    'id_supplier' => array(
                                                                        'type' => 'keyword', 
                                                                        'null_value' => 0,
                                                                        'index' => true,
                                                                        'eager_global_ordinals' => true
                                                                    ),

                                                                    'id_manufacturer' => array(
                                                                        'type' => 'keyword', 
                                                                        'null_value' => 0,
                                                                        'index' => true,
                                                                        'eager_global_ordinals' => true
                                                                    ),

                                                                    'id_color' => array(
                                                                        'type' => 'keyword', 
                                                                        'null_value' => 0,
                                                                        'index' => true,
                                                                        'eager_global_ordinals' => true
                                                                    ),

                                                                    'rating' => array(
                                                                        'type' => 'keyword', 
                                                                        'null_value' => 0,
                                                                        'index' => true,
                                                                    ),

                                                                    'id_default_category' => array(
                                                                        'type' => 'integer', 
                                                                        'null_value' => 0 
                                                                    ),



                                                                    'popularity' => array(
                                                                        'type' => 'integer', 
                                                                        'null_value' => 0
                                                                        ),

                                                                    'reduction_percent' => array(
                                                                        'type' => 'integer', 
                                                                        'null_value' => 0,
                                                                        'index' => true
                                                                    ),

                                                                    'is_reduced' => array(
                                                                        'type' => 'boolean'
                                                                    ),

                                                                    'reference' => array(
                                                                        'type' => 'keyword', 
                                                                        'null_value' => 0,
                                                                        'index' => true,

                                                                        ),

                                                                    'image_cover' => array(
                                                                        'type' => 'keyword',
                                                                        'index' => false,
                                                                        ),

                                                                    'image_title' => array(
                                                                        'type' => 'keyword',
                                                                        'index' => false,
                                                                        ),

                                                                    'product_link_title' => array(
                                                                        'type' => 'keyword',
                                                                        'index' => false,
                                                                        ),

                                                                    'price' => array(
                                                                        'type' => 'integer', 
                                                                        'null_value' => 0,
                                                                        'index' => true
                                                                    ),

                                                                    'old_price' => array(
                                                                        'type' => 'float', 
                                                                        'null_value' => 0 
                                                                    ),

                                                                    'id_product_categories' => array(
                                                                        'type' => 'keyword', 
                                                                        'null_value' => 0,
                                                                        'index' => true,
                                                                        'eager_global_ordinals' => true
                                                                    ),

                                                                    'date_add' => array(
                                                                        'type' => 'date',
                                                                        'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss',
                                                                        'index' => true
                                                                        ),

                                                                    'date_upd' => array(
                                                                        'type' => 'date',
                                                                        'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'
                                                                        ),

                                                                    'product_name' => array(
                                                                        'type' => 'text',
                                                                        "analyzer" =>  $lang_iso_code .'_analyzer'
                                                                    ),
                                                                    'product_heading' => array(
                                                                        'type' => 'keyword',
                                                                        "index" =>  false
                                                                    ),
                                                                    /*
                                                                    'product_description' => array(
                                                                        'type' => 'text',
                                                                        "analyzer" =>  $lang_iso_code .'_analyzer'
                                                                    ),
                                                                    */
                                                                    'product_color' => array(
                                                                        'type' => 'text',
                                                                        "analyzer" =>  $lang_iso_code .'_analyzer'
                                                                    ),
                                                                    'product_categories' => array(
                                                                        'type' => 'text', 
                                                                        "analyzer" =>  $lang_iso_code .'_analyzer'
                                                                    ),
                                                                    'product_manufacturer' => array(
                                                                        'type' => 'text',

                                                                    ),

                                                                    'product_supplier' => array(
                                                                        'type' => 'text'
                                                                    ),

                                                                    'product_link' => array(
                                                                        'type' => 'keyword',
                                                                        'index' => false

                                                                    )


                                                                )
                                        )
                    )
            );
```

Comment: Are you sure that is a query execution time, but not data fetching time? If your query returns 550K items that could just take long time to pass all data. Try to limit results to confirm if that is the case

Comment: @Alex I am certain that is not the fetching time, it only returns 48 elements, i have size => 48 at the beginning of the query, see the example above. There are 550k total products in the query (total hits)

Comment: Anyone can help with this?

Comment: I don't have Elastic sever to test at the moment. But just a guess, extend your `settings` => `'sort.field' => array('date_add','date_upd', 'reduction_percent','price'),` with `id_product_categories`

Comment: If this is your actual query (I don't see the aggregation part). A `term` query should be really fast -- but you're wrapping it inside a `filter` so ES will cache it. Normally having a cache is really good, but if it's trying to fit in your most expensive query ... maybe not.

You can check if it's still 500ms if you just run `query: { term: {  [id_product_categories] : { value :  "38231" }  } }`

Comment: Hello, i have changed the filter to a simple query, the timing is the same it did not change anything, i will add id_product_Categories to be indexed and see if that helps